# How can I grab http requests sent by any Desktop Application?

Tags: http, httpwebrequest, packet-sniffers, sniffing

I have one desktop application which was implemented in C#. This app uploads file to remote web server, I want to grab all http requests sent from this application. Is it possible to grab?

I don't have source code.

I am sorry if my question is incomplete.

Comment: Grab where? On the server the uploads are going to? Or intercept the uploads on the same machine the app is running on?

Comment: on my system where app is running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a great HTTP debugger called Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com), well worth investing a bit of time to learn.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to use fiddler for desktop application (which is not running in any browser)

Comment: Fiddler should switch your global settings an grab everything (browser and application), but if it doesn't hook in automatically, fiddler runs a local proxy you can direct traffic through for inspecting.  If you can't configure the proxy of the application, you can try using a reserve proxy (see http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/reverseproxy.asp).